# Unable to open the link in proxy

Tags: python, proxy

I am actually using a proxy to scrape data from some sites but the problem is sometimes some proy url returns nothing and programmed stopped after a few tries, I need some logic to overcome this issue so that even if IP does not respond program should renew the IP and try to open the page again, I am using TOR as a proxy in python.

Here is my website opening code:

```
mainPage = requests.get("http://proxy_IP/?link=http://example.com/")
mainTree = html.fromstring(mainPage.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put your code in while loop and give it certain condition, when that condition becomes TRUE, it means your page is properly opened.

```
mainPage = requests.get("http://proxy_IP/?link=http://example.com/")
mainTree = html.fromstring(mainPage.text)

mainTree
while (mainTree.xpath('boolean(some_xpath_to_be_true])') != True):
    mainPage = requests.get("http://proxy_IP/?link=http://example.com/")
    mainTree = html.fromstring(mainPage.text)
```

Now your mainTree contains the page source correctly.

Comment: Okay let me try if it works, I have another question too, I would love to ask that as well, It took me 24 hour just to think of any logic. Thankx

Comment: Sure, you can ask anything about python.